# Look up multiple values in a list and sort them in a new sheet

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

I have a data sheet that contains 9 columns corresponding to a name. But the names are repeated. So I want to create new sheets for all names and filter their data from the data sheet. The sheets must be updated when any changes are made on the data sheet.

I tried VLOOKUP but had some various problems, and it didn't work well for me. I've found a way that may help, but it's prepared for Excel. ( https://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/use-index-lookup-multiple-values-list )

In OpenOffice `ROW(1:1)` doesn't give a result. Dragging as an array also doesn't change the cells in the formula.  So are there any alternative ways to solve this problem? (OpenOffice solutions are preferred).

Comment: Are you using OpenOffice.org Calc or Excel?  They aren't synonymous.  If you want an Excel solution use the Excel tag and drop the other or vice-versa.  Of course, you could leave it as is and risk down-votes for it being too broad.

Comment: I'm using openoffice calc, but any alternative solutions with excel will also help me. That's why I put 2 tags in. I've also pointed out that an openoffice solution will be much more appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example from the link in the question almost works in LibreOffice.  To fix it, instead of `ROW(1:1)`, use `ROW($A$1:$A$6)`.

I am not sure what `ROW(1:1)` does in Excel, and I could not find an explanation online.  In Calc, `ROW($A$1:$A$6)` returns an array of 1 column x 6 rows: `{1;2;3;4;5;6}`.

So here is the full formula using the example.

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$2:$C$7,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$7=$A$9,ROW($A$2:$A$7)),ROW($A$1:$A$6))-1,3)),"",INDEX($A$2:$C$7,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$7=$A$9,ROW($A$2:$A$7)),ROW($A$1:$A$6))-1,3))
```

Be sure to enter it as an [array formula](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Array_Functions#Creating_Array_Formulas) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>